# iframe alternative to load external third party registration form

Tags: asp.net

Is there an alternative of using an iframe to load an external website that contains a registration form?

I read that iframes are bad practice these days

Comment: You can use [`JQuery`](http://jquery.com/) or [`Angular`](https://angularjs.org/) to load other website from your site.

Answer (score 0):

AS Lenonel mentioned in comment you can use jquery load method to display html like below.

```
<html>
    <header>
        <scriptsrc="/js/jquery.js"type="text/javascript">
    </header>
   <body>
      <div id='include-from-outside'></div>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            $('#include-from-outside').load('http://example.com/included.html');
        </script> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Refernce: http://shoaibfaruq.wordpress.com/2012/04/24/jquery-alternative-to-iframe/

Comment: I think so! It should work but one thing to remember you can code that page in your parent page.